# Add property to application.properties with Gradle task

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I run a Spring Boot application and I want to add a property to my application.properties file through a Gradle task. And then read it like you normally would in Spring.

```
@Value("${foo}")
```

So I have the following gradle task

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
}

tasks.register('foo') {
    doFirst {
        processResources {
            expand(project: project, foo: 'bar')
        }
    }

    dependsOn 'bootRun'
}
```

But when I run `gradle foo -q` the property `foo` is not filled in.